# Get the correct Timestamp for chat app in android, firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to know that how can I get the correct Time in milliseconds in android based upon the user's location, even if the time in the system is not correct or different than the real time.

I am building a chat app using Firebase and I need to provide a time stamp with every message sent & store it in Firebase, so that I call show the messaging in order of timestamp to the users.

I have tried the following way but it did not work because it just returns the same time that is of the system and not the accurate time -

```
DatabaseReference offsetRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(".info/serverTimeOffset");

    offsetRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: Time snapshot: " + snapshot);
            long offset = snapshot.getValue(Long.class);
            long estimatedServerTimeMs = System.currentTimeMillis() + offset;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            System.err.println("Listener was cancelled");
        }
    });
```

Comment: The problem is unclear, making it hard to help. What is "the correct Time"? Also: what did not work about this code? So: when you set a breakpoint on each line, and run the code in a debugger: which is the first line that doesn't do what you expect it to do? What did that line do? And what did you expect instead?

Comment: Apologies for incomplete information.

Comment: By correct time, I mean the actual time of the place where the user is currently at. For example, if the user's phone time has been set to 10:00 A.M but the actual time in the user's location is 1:00 P.M. Basically, I want to store accurate time stamps in database for sequential ordering of chats. This code is just returning wrong time of the system when I add the offset to System.currentTimeMillis(). I am a beginner with firebase, not really sure here.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

All timestamps with Firebase/Firestore use UTC timestamps and as such do not have a native offset. Instead, you must capture the timezone offset from the users' device and store it with the message or the user's public profile where you can call it from the device using:

```java
return TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

You can then add it to the user's message timestamp, this is because, by default, the timezone is added by your own OS when being read in a human-readable format.